# javafx 11 fires events randomly?

Tags: java, events, javafx, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag&drop in a tree view. I actually did it. It
works. In 1/3rd of the times.
Otherwise there are times when relevant events do not arrive, and events
kick in from nowhere.

Specifically I don't see the `dragDone` event to fire, although I call
`setDropCompleted(true)` in the `dragDropped` event.

If I do hand testing, I just can't see much correlation between events
arriving and the mouse movements I do.
`dragDropped` events came out of nowhere, some cells receive
`dragEnter/Exit/Over` event, some not, the event source is set to
misterious values.

This is how I test (see [DragAndDropTest.java](https://github.com/magwas/zenta3/blob/master/ui/src/test/java/org/rulez/demokracia/zenta3/editor/DragAndDropTest.java) for full code):

```
@Test
public void
when_the_drag_is_dropped_the_element_is_moved(
    final FxRobot robot
) {
    final ZentaTreeCell startCell = findCellFor(newElement);
    robot.drag(startCell);
    final ZentaTreeCell targetCell = findCellFor(thing);
    final int targetIndex = targetCell.getIndex();
    robot.moveTo(targetCell);
    robot.dropTo(targetCell);
    WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents();

    final ZentaTreeCell endCell = findCellFor(newElement);
    assertEquals(targetIndex + 1, endCell.getIndex());
}
```

And these are the relevant lines of my `TreeCell` implementation ([ZentaTreeCell](https://github.com/magwas/zenta3/blob/master/ui/src/main/java/org/rulez/demokracia/zenta3/editor/tree/ZentaTreeCell.java) for full code):

```
public class ZentaTreeCell extends TreeCell < ZentaElement > {

    public static final DataFormat ZENTA_FORMAT =
    new DataFormat("Zenta Elements");
    private final TreeView < ZentaElement > treeView;

    public ZentaTreeCell(final TreeView < ZentaElement > view) {
        super();
        treeView = view;
        setOnDragDetected((e) - > dragDetected(e));
        setOnDragEntered((e) - > dragEntered(e));
        setOnDragOver((e) - > dragOver(e));
        setOnDragExited((e) - > dragExited(e));
        setOnDragDropped((e) - > dragDropped(e));
        setOnDragDone((e) - > dragDone(e));
    }

    private void dragDone(final DragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("done\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
    }

    private void dragDropped(final DragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("dropped\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
        e.setDropCompleted(true);
        e.getDragboard().clear();
        e.consume();
        getStyleClass().remove("dragtarget");
        final ZentaTreeCell gestureSource = (ZentaTreeCell)
        e.getGestureSource();
        final ZentaTreeCell gestureTarget = (ZentaTreeCell)
        e.getGestureTarget();

        final TreeItem < ZentaElement > draggedItem = gestureSource.getTreeItem();
        final TreeItem < ZentaElement > draggedItemParent =
            draggedItem.getParent();
        final TreeItem < ZentaElement > droppeditem = gestureTarget.getTreeItem();
        final TreeItem < ZentaElement > droppedItemParent =
            droppeditem.getParent();
        final int indexInParent =
            droppedItemParent.getChildren().indexOf(droppeditem);
        draggedItemParent.getChildren().remove(draggedItem);
        droppedItemParent.getChildren().add(indexInParent + 1, draggedItem);
        treeView.getSelectionModel().select(draggedItem);
    }

    private void dragOver(final DragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("over\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
        e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        e.consume();
    }

    private void dragEntered(final DragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("entered\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
        getStyleClass().add("dragtarget");
        e.consume();
    }

    private void dragExited(final DragEvent e) {
        System.out.println("exited\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
        getStyleClass().remove("dragtarget");
        e.consume();
    }

    public void dragDetected(final MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("detected\n\tat " + this + "\n\t event: " + e);
        System.out.println("dragDetected");
        final Dragboard dragBoard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
        final Map < DataFormat, Object > map = new HashMap < > ();
        final ZentaElement item = getItem();
        map.put(ZENTA_FORMAT, item);
        System.out.println("item: " + item);
        dragBoard.setContent(map);

        e.consume();
    }

}
```

I guess I am missing something here, but after reading all the
documentation about drag&drop, I don't see what.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (vs a link to your real code)

Comment: The problem with drag&drop is that the minimal code is basically this complex. Take another look in the code. It does basically nothing else than drag&drop.

Comment: Maybe it's minimal, but it's not complete. We can't run this. Add an `Application` with a `main` and whatever is needed for us to copy-paste into our IDEs and run it.